# How do I use "-----" in php string functions?

Tags: php

I have a form that I have to pull some strings out of.  The form uses long dashed lines for dividing data sets.  It would be handy to use:

```
strpos($string, "----")
```

and

```
$file2= explode("-----", $file1)
```

but they don't seem to work.  I have replaced the "-" with "." and used "....." in the above to successfully extract the needed data, but it removes wanted dashes, such as 2-year-old, in the extracted data.  So I'm  back to wanting to use "----" in the code lines above.

I also tried to just replace "--" to ".." but the following doesn't work either.

```
$string = str_ireplace("--", "..",$string );
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: Please explicitly define what does "_doesn't work_" mean and how you determined that?

Comment: Why are you using `ireplace` in your last example?

Comment: Program uses "...." to explode and search through the string to find the data bits that I need.  The only problem is that any dashes in the extracted data have also been converted to ".".  In phrases like 2-year-old.

Comment: Meant to use str_replace.  Is that causing the problem?

Comment: @user1028866 nopez. Those dashes probably aren't the characters you think they are. Inspect them with a decent text-editor to find out what characters they are

Comment: I'd like to see the string you are working with. 

`<?php
$my_str = "test-----12345-----1234567890-----one more time";
$my_new_str = explode("-----",$my_str);
print_r($my_new_str);
?>`

Comment: -------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Unnamed, 2009/05/25, dk b/ filly -- Danzig Key (89), by Danzig (77)
        (Application Pending)

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Unnamed, 2009/04/05, dk b/ filly -- Golden Thatch (87), by Slew o' Gold (80)

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Comment: $string = str_ireplace("-", ".",$string ); works with string but $string = str_ireplace("--", "..",$string ); doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works perfectly fine.

```
    <?php

    $test = 'name----address----2-year-old----dob';

    $test_chunks = explode("----", $test);

    echo $test_chunks[2];

    ?>
```

Displays "2-year-old" w/o any issues. If you must convert the dashes to something else, try this as well:

```
    test_convert = str_replace("----", "....", $test);
```

...and then explode using periods.

Comment: That's how I've been doing it.  I just would prefer not to lose the dashed that are parts of compound words.  So I have to figure out why the string in my file wont work like your first example?

Comment: As I said, you can keep using the dashes, but I tested the code above and it works fine. Copy/paste it and see if that works for you as well (it should). Now, if you still have issues, try the str_replace and use periods to explode the string (just one extra line of code after you get the string data)...but like I said, you really shouldn't have to do that at all. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Scott.  I know this seems obvious.  It just isn't working on my data string.  I can't figure out why.  Thanks for your advice.  It verified what I thought should work.  Best Regards